# youtube xml parser for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am working on iphone application which will read the following youtube page source:

```
     view-source:http://www.youtube.com/user/danielmorcombefd
```

and then save the links of all the videos available on any particular youtube channel like the href node of the line below:

```
    <h4><a class="title" href="/watch?v=ouMPBbZ2vKw&context=C2ab41ADOEgsToPDskJnhTjKl70yDQdEkLJb0So8" dir="ltr">
```

Can anybody suggest a source code link for youtube xml reader. Solutions are appreciate in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alternate**

You can also use the JSON format. You can add `?alt=json` to the URL to get the JSON version of it. Then you can use JSON library. [JSON library](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)

Comment: i just want to read one tag i.e. data-video-ids, anything simple